# How to avoid recursive appearance of array elements in smarty nested foreach loops?

Tags: arrays, loops, foreach, smarty

I've two arrays:

```
$data.applicable_states
Array
(
[applicable_states] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
        )
)
```

and another array is `all_states`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [state_name] => Alabama
            [abbreviation] => AL
            [created_at] => 1398342353
            [updated_at] => 1398342353
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [state_name] => Alaska
            [abbreviation] => AK
            [created_at] => 1398342353
            [updated_at] => 1398342353
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [state_name] => Arizona
            [abbreviation] => AZ
            [created_at] => 1398342353
            [updated_at] => 1398342353
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [state_name] => Arkansas
            [abbreviation] => AR
            [created_at] => 1398342353
            [updated_at] => 1398342353
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [state_name] => California
            [abbreviation] => CA
            [created_at] => 1398342353
            [updated_at] => 1398342353
        )
)
```

Now I want to print all the elements from the second array into a selct control but have to show the elements selected whose ids are matching with the first array. So for it I wrote following logic but it's not working.

```
<select id="example28" multiple="multiple" name="applicable_states[]">
    {foreach from=$all_states item=state key=key}
      {foreach from=$data.applicable_states item=pre key='index'}
        <option value="{$state.id}" {if $state.id == $pre} selected="selected"{/if}>  {$state.state_name}</option>
      {/foreach}
    {/foreach}
</select>
```

After executing above code I'm getting the names of states selected but every state name gets repeated four times(i.e. equal to the total no. of elements contained in the first array). How to avoid this repetion of elemets. Please someone help me out from this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "Smarty Best Practices" - http://www.smarty.net/best_practices. In your case you mix application logic and view-layer data. And as a result you've got issues.

You can easy solve such problem if you move logic into the PHP file (logic-layer) and pass result to the templater. For example.

PHP:

```
$states_data_for_select = $all_states;

foreach($states_data_for_select as $key => $state) {
    $id = $state['id'];
    $states_data_for_select[$key]['is_selected'] = in_array($id, $applicable_states);
}
```

Smarty template:

```
<select id="example28" multiple="multiple" name="applicable_states[]">
    {foreach from=$states_data_for_select item=state}
        <option value="{$state.id}" {if $state.is_selected}selected="selected"{/if}> {$state.state_name}</option>
    {/foreach}
</select>
```